# Python script executable with py2exe or pyinstaller

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller

My program contains 3 files (2x .py and .json). I would like to make single exe file. I tried py2exe with basic setup settings:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console = ['my_main_file.py'])
```

It doesn't work. When I run exe file from dist directory terminal window blinks for a second. I tried also pyinstller but result is similar. How can I make it?

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: Python 2.7.10, Windows 10 64bit. In past I made simple script executable and it worked but it was only 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I launched my .exe file from terminal and received an error "there is no file myfile.json" or something like that. I simply copied this file to disc directory and program works.